# Rails / Bootstrap Navbar / jQuery differences between localhost and deployed (Heroku)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, localhost, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue while developing a basic Rails application. I've implemented Twitter Bootstrap and its responsive navbar. When the page is loaded on mobile screens the navbar should slide down and slide back up as designed. I'm trying to figure out why certain scenarios are making the jQuery animation glitchy and unusable. I want to make sure that this problem won't manifest in deployment and because it's quite annoying.

My scenarios are:

---

### Development server on localhost

**Chrome (17.0.963.83)**

- Animation works fine.
- No issues in Developer Tools

**Firefox (7.0.1)**

- Animation glitchy.
- Firebug shows a 3 step process happening in

  ```
  `<div class="nav-collapse" style="height: auto;">...</div>`

  `<div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">...</div>`

  `<div class="nav-collapse" style="height: auto;">...</div>`
  ```

**Safari on iPhone 4 and iPhone Simulator**

- Animation glitchy.
- Apparent 3 step process as well.

---

### Deployed on Heroku

**Chrome (17.0.963.83)**

- Works fine

**Firefox (7.0.1)**

- Works fine

**Safari on iPhone 4 and iPhone Simulator**

- Works fine

---

### As requested...

**application.js - Where I'm calling the scripts**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-transition.js
//= require bootstrap-alert.js
//= require bootstrap-button.js
//= require bootstrap-carousel.js
//= require bootstrap-collapse.js
//= require bootstrap-dropdown.js
//= require bootstrap-modal.js
//= require bootstrap-tooltip.js
//= require bootstrap-scrollspy.js
//= require bootstrap-tab.js
//= require bootstrap-typeahead.js
//= require_tree .
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      mail (~> 2.4.0)
    actionpack (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    activemodel (3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.2)
      activemodel (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
    activesupport (3.2.2)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    journey (1.0.3)
    jquery-rails (2.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.5)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    multi_json (1.1.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    pg (0.13.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.2)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      activerecord (= 3.2.2)
      activeresource (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.2)
    railties (3.2.2)
      actionpack (= 3.2.2)
      activesupport (= 3.2.2)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.1.15)
    sass-rails (3.2.4)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.1.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.32)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  json
  mysql2
  pg
  rails (= 3.2.2)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

---

[JSFiddle with my basic code](http://jsfiddle.net/shawnphoffman/jDMnD/2/)

---

**bootstrap-collapse.js**

I think that something in this could be causing the issue but I'm not sure.

```
!function( $ ){

  "use strict"

  var Collapse = function ( element, options ) {
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.collapse.defaults, options)

    if (this.options["parent"]) {
      this.$parent = $(this.options["parent"])
    }

    this.options.toggle && this.toggle()
  }

  Collapse.prototype = {

    constructor: Collapse

  , dimension: function () {
      var hasWidth = this.$element.hasClass('width')
      return hasWidth ? 'width' : 'height'
    }

  , show: function () {
      var dimension = this.dimension()
        , scroll = $.camelCase(['scroll', dimension].join('-'))
        , actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('.in')
        , hasData

      if (actives && actives.length) {
        hasData = actives.data('collapse')
        actives.collapse('hide')
        hasData || actives.data('collapse', null)
      }

      this.$element[dimension](0)
      this.transition('addClass', 'show', 'shown')
      this.$element[dimension](this.$element[0][scroll])

    }

  , hide: function () {
      var dimension = this.dimension()
      this.reset(this.$element[dimension]())
      this.transition('removeClass', 'hide', 'hidden')
      this.$element[dimension](0)
    }

  , reset: function ( size ) {
      var dimension = this.dimension()

      this.$element
        .removeClass('collapse')
        [dimension](size || 'auto')
        [0].offsetWidth

      this.$element[size ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapse')

      return this
    }

  , transition: function ( method, startEvent, completeEvent ) {
      var that = this
        , complete = function () {
            if (startEvent == 'show') that.reset()
            that.$element.trigger(completeEvent)
          }

      this.$element
        .trigger(startEvent)
        [method]('in')

      $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('collapse') ?
        this.$element.one($.support.transition.end, complete) :
        complete()
    }

  , toggle: function () {
      this[this.$element.hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : 'show']()
    }

  }

  /* COLLAPSIBLE PLUGIN DEFINITION
  * ============================== */

  $.fn.collapse = function ( option ) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('collapse')
        , options = typeof option == 'object' && option
      if (!data) $this.data('collapse', (data = new Collapse(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }

  $.fn.collapse.defaults = {
    toggle: true
  }

  $.fn.collapse.Constructor = Collapse


 /* COLLAPSIBLE DATA-API
  * ==================== */

  $(function () {
    $('body').on('click.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function ( e ) {
      var $this = $(this), href
        , target = $this.attr('data-target')
          || e.preventDefault()
          || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') //strip for ie7
        , option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'toggle' : $this.data()
      $(target).collapse(option)
    })
  })

}( window.jQuery );
```

Comment: Can you list how and where you've included the js files? Also - check your gemfile.lock to see exactly which versions are being used locally - try running it from a pristine bundle

Comment: @JulesCopeland - Added the changes. I'm fairly new to Rails so I'll do some quick research on running it from a pristine bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using RVM locally? If you are - try setting up a clean gemset for your app and running bundle install again.

That way you'll know that you're using the exact same versions as on your heroku deployment.

<strike>If that doesn't fix your problem, then there might be a bug in the bootstrap code itself - try raising an issue on the bootstrap issues age. (Or search the existing issues at least)</strike>

As suggested in the comments (and for future googlers...) - Check your compiled assets. Once you've ensured that you're running the same gem versions, make sure you're referencing the exact same asset files. Delete all of the precompiled assets in the public folder and change `config.assets.enabled = true` in `application.rb`.

This is especially important on Heroku deployments.

Comment: Installed RVM. Built a new gemset. Verified that my gems are the same. Same issue still occurring. I'm going to raise an issue and report back.

Comment: Figured it out. The solution to this problem was with the assets pipeline. When application.js was being precompiled it was causing duplicate bootstrap .js files (optimized and unoptimized). I solved the problem by deleting all of the precompiled assets in the public folder and changing `config.assets.enabled = true` in application.rb. Suggest it in your answer and I'll be more than happy to upvote and mark the answer.