# Why does my drop down-menu work on my local server but not when I push to heroku?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

When I test my site locally it works fine, but once I push to heroku the drop down menu doesn't work.

my application.js file contains this:

```
    //= require bootstrap
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require_tree .
```

my application.html.erb file contains this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> <%= full_title(yield(:title)) %> </title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>

<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>  
    <div class="container">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my header partial which is where the drop down menus are, contains this

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav pull-left">
        <li>
      <%= link_to image_tag("WML_header2.png", :alt => 'Wheres My Lan'), home_path%> 
        </li>
      </ul>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            </br>
            <li><%= link_to "Heat Map",  heatMap_path %></li>
            <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "New Update",  new_message_path %></li>


            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                View <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Reports", reports_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Statistics", stats_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Account <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", settings_path %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Admin sign in", signin_path %></li>

          <% end %>
          <li><%= link_to "About",  about_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Sounds similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966064/rails-bootstrap-navbar-jquery-differences-between-localhost-and-deployed-he/9990176#9990176

Answer (score 0):

What is the generated HTML? Are there any errors as reported by Chrome's Developer Toolbar?

My guess it is expecting a javascript file in a certain location, and it is not seeing it there.

Comment: there are no errors. I also imported bootstrap into my custom.css file so everything should be there

Comment: Don't know what else to tell ya, except go see if Fiddler could give you any more clues as to why it's not working. Perhaps you'll find that one file is not getting a 200.

Answer (score 0):

Check the order that jQuery is loading in. jQuery "first", all your other plugins come later.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to move `//=require bootstrap` right after `//= require jquery`? This solved my similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem, and Paolo del Mundo's suggestion helped me find what I was doing wrong. I checked out the HTML in Google Chrome, and discovered a couple errors cropping up:

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
  (Not Found)

I did a StackOverflow search for that error, and hey, guess what? Turns out I forgot to set "config.assets.compile = true" in config/environments/production.rb.

/Picardfacepalm

I set that, added/comitted/pushed to Git, pushed to Heroku, refreshed Heroku page - and all was well and good in the universe.